# How to find the key corresponding to the maximum value in a dictionary of dictionary using max() function?

Tags: python, dictionary, key, max

I know how to find the key corresponding to the maximum value in a dictionary, thanks to the answers to the following quesyions on Stackoverflow -

[Print the key of the max value in a dictionary the pythonic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402015/print-the-key-of-the-max-value-in-a-dictionary-the-pythonic-way),

[key corresponding to maximum value in python dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227291/key-corresponding-to-maximum-value-in-python-dictionary),

[Getting key with maximum value in dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268272/getting-key-with-maximum-value-in-dictionary), etc.

But I am not being able to understand how these will work out for a dictionary of dictionary.

Example-
I have a dictionary of dictionary `d[x][l]`. Suppose, I need to find the following-
For a particular `l='green'`, I need to find the corresponding value of `x` for which `d[x]['green']` is maximum.

How to use the `max()` function in this case? I want to avoid looping over. I was hoping to find something equivalent to the MATLAB way of doing it in a matrix- `max(d(:,l))`.

`d[x][l]` takes integer values, and so does `x`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lambda:

```
max(d, key=lambda x: d[x]['green'])
```

The `key` function is called with each key in `d`; if you want to find the key for which `d[key]['green']` is highest, you return exactly that.

Demo:

```
>>> d = {10: {'green': 42}, 81: {'green': 5, 'blue': 100}}
>>> max(d, key=lambda x: d[x]['green'])
10
```

`d[10]['green']` is the highest value, so `10` is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still learning how the lambda operator works!

Comment: What will the answer be, if x takes on values from a list, instead of all the keys in the dictionary?

Comment: @SatarupaGuha: `lambda` simply creates a function, with one expression that whose outcome is returned. `lambda x: d[x]['green']` is the same as `def somefunction(x): return d[x]['green']` except you don't have to give it a name.

Comment: @SatarupaGuha: `d` is a dictionary, looping over the dictionary (as `max()` will do) yields keys, so `x` is one key in `d` for each call.  `d[x]` is then one of the values in `d`, which according to your question are all dictionaries with at least a key `'green'` in it.

Comment: I want to loop over a selected list of keys, and not all the keys. For example- maxlNeighbor=0
        for item in g.neighbors(u):
            if degree[item][l]>maxlNeighbor:
                maxlNeighbor=degree[item][l]
                v=item

Comment: @SatarupaGuha: then pass that list to `max()`; the key will still be the same, provided the list is a subset of all keys in `d`.

Comment: @SatarupaGuha: so `maxlNeighbor = max(g.neighbors(u), lambda x: d[x][l])`, using the same `g`, `u` and `l` as the code in your comment.

Comment: @MartijnPieters how can i change the statement that finds the max if i want to find the max of something like: `d['green'][key]`

Comment: @ifreak: just remember that the `key` function is called for each value in the iterable. As long as that function returns a value over which to calculate the maximum it'll work.

Comment: @MartijnPieters assuming the following dict : `d = {'A':{'B':20,'C':50},'AA':{'B':10,'C':70}}`
using : `max(d, key=lambda x: d['A'][x])` does not work, why?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think what i should do is : `max(d['A'], key=lambda x: d['A'][x])` right ?

Comment: @ifreak: exactly, because then you are looping over the keys of `d['A']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {10: 100, 81:500}
s=max(d,key=d.get)
print(s)
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain or link relevant docs to understand how does your answer work?

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Comment: @aaossa thank u for your opinion from next tilme i will ensure it ...